# UPDATE-SQL value in table with another value in table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update a value in table with value in other table

```
String sql6="UPDATE project.wish_list SET project.wish_list.quantity= project.book.quantity";
```

But don't work why?

thank you

Comment: In human language, what you are saying is : set the wish list quantity to some value of book quantity, but I'm not going to tell you from which book. Why do you think he is unable to do that ?

Comment: @tvCa Real. I forgot to put in the isbn condition XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the tables:

```
sql6="UPDATE project.wish_list join project.book on <condition> SET project.wish_lista.quantity= project.book.quantity";
```

Comment: error ora-00971 missing set keyword: i tried sql6="UPDATE project.wish_list join project.book on project.book.isbn = project.wish_list.isbn SET project.wish_list.quantity= project.book.quantity";

Comment: @neo999 Can you try this: `UPDATE project.wish_list SET project.wish_lista.quantity= (SELECT project.book.quantity FROM project.book WHERE project.book.isbn = project.wish_list.isbn)`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have a syntax error:

```
UPDATE project.wish_list SET project.wish_lista.quantity= project.book.quantity
```

The "a" in whish_list -> "project.wish_lista.quantity"... it should be:

```
UPDATE project.wish_list SET project.wish_list.quantity= project.book.quantity
```

Comment: yes I know, It's typo error when i write post, sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
Update wish_list set wish_list.quantity= book.quantity from wish_list as wish_list     

inner join book as book on wish_list.ID=book .ID
```

Comment: "on wish_list.ID"  What is ID? (I have ISBN in book table and book wish list) thanks

Comment: ID is Primary Key For wish_list and Foreign Key for book or vice versa